# Como usar o Include para objetos que estão dentro de uma lista

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho os seguintes objetos em meu contexto EF6.

```
public class Produto
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}

public class VedaItem
{
    public int Item {get;set;}
    public float Valor {get;set;}
    public Guid ProdutoId {get;set;}

    public virtual Produto Produto {get;set;}
}

public class Venda
{
    public DateTime DataVenda {get;set;}
    public string Numero {get;set;}
    public List<VendaItem> Itens {get;set;}

}
```

Eu não uso LazyLoading, logo preciso de usar *Include* para acessar os relacionamentos com `Venda` para gerar um relatório.

Preciso de acessar os dados de Produto que estão em `VendaItem`.

Tentei fazer o include da seguinte forma.

```
var relatorio = contexto.Set<Venda>()
     .Include(v => v.Itens.Produto);
     .Select(v => new 
     {
        NomeProduto = v.Itens.Produto.Nome
     });
```

Porem o VisualStudio nem me permite digitar isso: `v => v.Itens.Produto`.

Como eu faço para conseguir acessar os dados da entidade Produto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria dessa forma:

```
 var relatorio = contexto.Set<Venda>()
                 .Include(v => v.Itens.Select(p=> p.Produto));
```

Vai retornar a lista de vendas, com os itens e produtos carregados.

Comment: Obrigado! vou testar